# Vue js. How do I get current url in index.html file?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

Vue js. How do I get current url in index.html file?
With pure js in index.html I get only url of the start page. To get the url of the other pages I have to refresh or the value of the initial page remains.

```
<!-- index.php laravel blade -->

<div id="ui">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
<script>
    window.CanvasUI = @json($config);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset(mix('js/canvas-ui.js')) }}"></script>
```

Comment: Please add some minimal codes that you've done to solve the issue, so that others know how to help.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to get baseUrl in VueJs is

var baseUrl = window.location.origin

Answer (score 0):

With pure JS:

```
window.location.href
```

Comment: With window.location.href in the index.html of a single page application (spa), the url value of the initial page remains also in the other pages if the page is not reloaded.